# how to prevent arraylist from adding the same string twice?

Tags: ios, swift, arraylist

I have a viewController that has a variable and it's getting the value of this variable from another view controller so the variable is like this for example..

```
var name = "Step-Up to Emergency Medicine"
```

and there is a button when clicked it's append this string to an arraylist

```
@IBAction func add(_ sender: Any) {
        myArray.append(name)
}
```

my question is how to prevent the arraylist from adding the same string value twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the string isn't already in the array before appending, like this:

```
@IBAction func add(_ sender: Any) {
   if !myArray.contains(name) {
       myArray.append(name)
   }
}
```

Comment: Better to use a set but if your list contains just a few elements you won't notice any difference.